# vs c++ cross endian union

Tags: c++, endianness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to read big endian data with little endian program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022462/any-way-to-read-big-endian-data-with-little-endian-program)

I have the union struct below in my project which I'm trying to modify to read a big endian file and as the program is running on x86 it attempts to read the file as little endian and returns the wrong result from the union. Is there any way to modify the union to read it in big endian format? or an alternative method of getting the correct data type?

```
struct AptConstItem {
    AptConstItemType type;
    union {
        const char *strvalue;
        unsigned int numvalue;
    };
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022462/any-way-to-read-big-endian-data-with-little-endian-program?rq=1

Comment: No, there is no way to modify the union. One way or another you need to swap the bytes after you have read the data.

Comment: but will swapping the bytes after the union return the correct data type?

Comment: @john You don't modify the union, and you don't swap bytes.  You construct the value you need from the input bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You use the same basic technique regardless of endianness: to read
big endian:

```
uint32_t
readBigEndian( std::istream& binaryInput )
{
    uint32_t result 
            = (binaryInput.get() << 24) & 0xFF000000;
    result |= (binaryInput.get() << 16) & 0x00FF0000;
    result |= (binaryInput.get() <<  8) & 0x0000FF00;
    result |= (binaryInput.get()      ) & 0x000000FF;
    return result;
}
```

For little endian, you just reverse the order of the shifts and masks.

Comment: sorry I've only recently started learning c++ and I'm not sure how I would apply this to the union?

Comment: @Twisted89 You wouldn't apply it directly (and this has nothing to do with C++).  There's nothing you can apply directly to the union: you have to first find out how the data was written, then do more or less the opposite to read.  In this case, the type will probably be some sort of integer, read as above (adjusted to the correct number of bytes).  Once you've read that, you have to use it to determine whether you read a string or an unsigned int.  If it's a string, how you read it will depend on how it is output.